# Update custom option in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-options

I have a simple product with a date custom option. When I click on the date a calendar opens and I select the date. After adding the product to cart, I can see the product along with the date as a custom option. Now I have to update this date on the cart page and save the value. I have found some solution in magento1. But I have to do it in magento2.

Answer (score 0):

For the Date value you need to create one column in  "***quote_item***" table. and add that value in ***checkout_cart_add_product_complete*** Observer